# Is there any d3 function like scalePoint but for two dimensions?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I want to place clusters like in this block:
https://bl.ocks.org/SpaceActuary/d6b5ca8e5fb17842d652d0de21e88a05

However, I want the clusters to be on a 2d grid rather than in a line and specify range in each dimension so that I can have e.g. a short but wide lattice.

I tried playing with scalePoint range but couldn't get it to return an array.

I could manually compute positions, but would be a lot cleaner if there's already a built-in way to do this in d3.

Comment: Just use **two** scales: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255256/5768908

Comment: I tried adding yScale in the same way as being used for x. d3 positioned the clusters along the diagonal rather than in a lattice

Comment: That example relies on splitting from two classes of categories and will generate a lattice of dimensions |category A| x |category B|. Maybe solution is to split my single category into two of size #desired rows x #desired columns? Still a little messier than I'm hoping for